# accessing map from a namespace

Tags: c++, dictionary, namespaces

I got a namespace in map.h header file, and defined the map in map.cpp file as

#### map.h

```
    namespace mymap{
     .....
   }
```

#### map.cpp

```
   namespace mymap{
     static const map<int, string> mymap{
          {0, "zero"},
          {1, "one"}....
     }
   }
```

I want to access this map in another .cpp file called summary.cpp, when ever I do that the compiler throws an error mymap is not a not a member of mymap?

Why is this happening, how can I access that map in summary.cpp, I have included mymap.h in summary.cpp and using mymap::mymap to access it

Comment: In `summary.cpp` are you accessing it as `mymap::mymap`? Or `using namespace mymap?`

Comment: yes, I am using that sorry for not mentioning here

Comment: I just realized you declared the map in your `cpp` file. You need to declare the map in the `.h` file, then `#include map.h` in `summary.cpp`.

Comment: as per the terms I need to use map in the cpp file itself, is there any way that I can access it without moving the map into my .h file

Comment: If you move the map to the `.h` file, you can access it from any `.cpp` file that `#include`s the `.h` file. Both `map.cpp` and `summary.cpp` can access it this way. If you declare it in `map.cpp` only, then the only way to access it in `summary.cpp` would be to `#include map.cpp` which I *strongly* discourage.

Comment: I cannot use #include map.cpp, which is throwing me some more errors. Can I declare map in .h and define it in my .cpp file

Answer (score 0):

1. The keyword `static` used on a namespace-scope definition or declaration makes it translation-unit-local.
2. `const` in the above situation would also imply `static`, unless overridden with `extern`.
3. If you don't have a previous declaration for your symbol in a translation-unit (if not defined in that TU, it should come from a header which is also included first thing in the TU defining it, in order to detect mismatches), trying to use it is an error.